# Views exposed filter auto submit loses focus

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have setup a view with ajax enabled. I have also added an exposed filter with autosubmit on so that as the user types in the text field the view will automatically update. The problem is that when the form autosubmits, the text box loses focus.

I have read that I need to separate the exposed form into a separate block, however this option is not available as my view is a block itself.

Any help would be appreciated, as it is a real pain having to keep clicking in the text box to keep typing.

Comment: This is a known problem: http://drupal.org/node/1217948 and is not that easy to fix

Comment: Can you do a exposed_filter_alter to manually change values and add your own javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You really only have one choice here.

One way or another you need to (re)move your form out of the views.

The reason why the exposed filter looses focus is because the entire view is being replaced on ajax. If your form is being render by the same view there's just no way you're going to be able to keep focus.

Solutions (All involve moving your form out of the view):

- Use views "exposed filters in a block" **Recommended option**
- Set up a custom block to render the expose filter form (Require writing code)

  - See [views_plugin_exposed_form::render_exposed_form](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503182721/http://www.drupalcontrib.org:80/api/drupal/contributions!views!plugins!views_plugin_exposed_form.inc/function/views_plugin_exposed_form::render_exposed_form/7) for an example on how to do this.

Below are some options you should avoid, but mentioning here as a last resort.

- You can always just "hack" your views.tpl.php to move your expose form out of the main view div. I use "hack" here because this is not a nice option. This will place the form right above your view, but views JS code is only going to replace the view div. That being said the JS isn't going to just work. You'll need to fix that.
- Then as a last resort you can always just use JS to move your form. This one is highly discourage. Because again the form is going to loose the JS behaviors after views updates the display

Comment: Just in case anyone else was wondering, I believe the solution recommended here by @ericduran to select Views' option to put "exposed form in block" is just available if the view is of a page (it's not available for a view as block).

Answer (score 3):

Also a workaround for the core problem, but [including this js](https://drupal.org/comment/7736343#comment-7736343) in my theme solved this problem for me.